# Flask : ImmutableMultiDict has no attribute

Tags: python, flask

I wrote a small flask file:

**myapp.py**

```
@APP.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    return flask.render_template('login.html')

@APP.route('/loginNext', methods=['POST','GET'])
def loginNext():
    user=request.form.username
    passw=request.form.password
    return str(user)+str(pass)
```

**login.html**

```
<form id="foo" method="post" action="/loginNext">
Username : <input type="text" name='username' value="admin">
Password : <input type="password" name='password' value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I am trying to do request.form.username, I am getting

***AttributeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object has no attribute 'username' ***

I read on stackoverflow as well as other places but didnot work. I tried doing request.form.get('username',None') that did not fetch the username.

Comment: got if fixed.it was due to post method that I was putting in the login method as well. now i can get the username as request.form['username']

Answer (score 6):

`<input type="text" name='username' value="admin">` was your input in `.html` file so to access in flask It is done in this way

`username = request.form['username']`

and you get the data as username .. same for password also.

Answer (score 0):

if form tag contains below:-

```
<input type="text" name='username'>
```

In Flask Function, we can access it in 2 ways:-

```
username = request.form['username']

username = request.form.get('username')
```